# Binomial expansion up to $x^2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

1. Use the binomial expansion to show that $ \sqrt{(4-x)} $ is $2- \frac14x + kx^2 $
2. Use the binomial expansion to show that $ \sqrt{\frac{1+4x}{1-x}} $ is $ 1 + \frac52x - \frac58x^2 $

No idea where to start. Help appreciated

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Do you know what the binomial expansion is?

Comment: Yes, however I don't understand how to do it with non integer powers

Comment: $(1+x)^r=1+rx+\frac{r(r-1)}2x^2+...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, it became apparent that you were not aware that the binomial expansion  $$(x+y)^n=x^n+nx^{n-1}y+\dfrac{n(n-1)}2x^{n-2}y^2+...$$ can be valid even when $n$ is not an integer, though in that case it becomes an infinite series.

That is where you should start.  Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I thought that was the expansion only when it is in the format $ (1+x)^n $, and that the expansion of $ (x+y)^n $ involves using nCr?

Comment: What I wrote can be valid as well; note $\binom n0=1, \binom n1=n, \binom n2=\dfrac{n(n-1)}2, ...$